# Combination of loop with recursion function

Tags: python

Having the following code:

```
def choose_sets(lst,k):
 if k == 0:
      return [[]]
 if len(lst) == k:
      return [lst]
 else:
      return choose_sets(lst[1:],k)+[[lst[0]]+i for i in choose_sets(lst[1:],k-1)]
```

How does `i for i in choose_sets(lst[1:],k-1)` work? Is it possible to give up on the loop and instead to write this?

```
+[[lst[0]]+choose_sets(lst[1:],k-1)]
```

this function returns list that contains all the different lists at length K that can be created out of the original list's members (the order isn't important)

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations? This might be similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: @AMacK But why "i for i in " must be written? Why "choose_sets(lst[1:],k)+[[lst[0]]+choose_sets(lst[1:],k-1)] " isn't enough?

Comment: You really don't want to write something which recursively appends to a list; since appending is itself O(N), that will be O(N^2). Terrible for scalability. Like @AMacK said, read through [docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and pick the right tool for the job. This code is like instant-fail in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i for i in choose_sets(lst[1:],k-1)`

yields all the sets whose length is k-1 and does not contain lst[0]. In the other word, we got a list, whose elements are lists with length k-1. Adding lst[0] to each of them, we got all K-length sets that contains lst[0].

Plus `choose_sets(lst[1:],k)`, which yields all K-length sets that does not contain lst[0], we got all
K-length sets.

`Is it possible to give up on the loop and instead to write this?`

No. `+[[lst[0]]+choose_sets(lst[1:],k-1)]` yields a list whose first element is with length 1 and all other elements are with length k-1, this is obviousely what we expected.